# What is the area of ​the triangle $MNP$ below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: The image below represents a farm in the shape of an equilateral triangle, which is divided into $7$ fields by the $AL, BT,$ and $CR$ hedges, all having the same length. Fields like the $AMR$ measure $8$ hectares, and those that are like the $BNMR$, $22$ hectares. How big is the $MNP$ field?
(Answer$5ha$)

[image]

My progress:

[image]

$AL = CR = BT \implies g+e+MN = g+e+PN+g+e+PM\\
\therefore \triangle PMN(equilateral\\
\frac{S_\triangle AMR}{S_\triangle PMN }= \frac{e.g}{x^2}\implies \frac{8}{S}=\frac{e.g}{x^2}\\
\frac{S_\triangle AMR}{S_\triangle LMC }= \frac{e.g}{(x+e).(x+g)}\implies \frac{8}{S+22}=\frac{e.g}{(x+e)(x+g)}\\
T.Menelaus: \triangle BCR-AL: b.(g+x).b = a.e.(a+b)\implies\\
b^2.(g+x)=a.e(l)\therefore l = \frac{b^2(g+x)}{ae}$

...???

Comment: In the meantime, I found a similar question, so deleted my answer which seems almost similar to one of the answers there. So... Does this answer your question? [Area of an equilateral triangle divided by three lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616331/area-of-an-equilateral-triangle-divided-by-three-lines)